# decimal places in mutate results in R

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, shinydashboard, mutate

I am building a shiny app, and i have difficulties fixing the decimal places in mutate results.
What i need is that, to add comma in the GDP.Scenario & Job.Scenario, meaning that the numbers appear as 1,000,000 for example.

The code and the Shiny result are as in the pictures.
[image]

[image]

i tried to add some specifications in the mutate function such as across() but it did not work

Comment: You need to provide sample code with sample data that represents your problem and can be copied, not retyped from an image.  Anyway, looks like you've left out the part where the table is output.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should provide a reproducible example with code and data because others could help you. This link might help you: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2020/10/how-to-make-a-reprex/

Comment: The issue is almost certainly is the displaying the table, not in the `mutate()` call which creates the column.   Please provide the code which displays the table.